# How do I get specified data from multiple cells and then averaging them?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

1) Given the text "6x22kg" in a cell, how can I get the '6' and '22'?

2) I made my desired result manually in the following image. The cells marked in red is the input, and the cells marked in green is my desired result.
How to do this?

Image example: [Dataset, input in red, desired result in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29qLr.png)

I hope the image example is clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: You need to describe the rules for the format of the input values. Are they all guaranteed to be 1 digit followed by "x", then 2 digits followed by "kg"? Or are any of these allowed: "10x23kg" (times is more than 9), "6x 23kg" (space included) "6x22g" (grams instead of kilograms), "6X22kg" (upper case)?, "6x22.5kg" weight is not a whole number of kilograms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the data is in Cells C4:G4. 
Put following formula in H4 for Average of 'Times'

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(LEFT(C4:G4,FIND("X",UPPER(C4:G4))-1)))
```

Press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to make it an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

In I4 put the following Array Formula. Again ensure that you press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar.

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(MID(C4:G4,FIND("X",UPPER(C4:G4))+1,LEN(C4:G4)-FIND("X",UPPER(C4:G4))-2)))
```

Formula will work even if you put x or X as multiplier sign. It's assumed that weight is always shown in KG or kg and if any other metric is used its abbreviation is two characters long.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use `SEARCH` in place of `FIND` - it isn't case-sensitive so you can then dispense with `UPPER`.....